# Finding Asymmetric Pairs using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am trying to analyze the social network data which contains `follower` and `followee` pairs.

I want to find the `asymmetric pairs` **(A follows B but B doesn't follow A)** using MapReduce *(Hadoop)*.

With this pair data, however, I am not sure how the `mappers` and **one** `reducer` should handle the data since separating the pairs will affect the results.

Can someone explain to me how I can use MapReduce to **find the asymmetric pairs** from the massive data using MapReduce?

Thank you very much.

p.s. I hope there is a way to use many Mappers for this kind of problem even though I might have to use only one Reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.
(It works but it **may not** be the **optimal** solution. If someone have a better answer please tell me.)

`Each mapper` counts the number of follower/followee pairs **while making the order of this pair** to have small number comes first and the larger number comes second.

> 0 -> 1 (ID 0 follows ID 1)
> 1 -> 0 (ID 1 follows ID 0)
>
> **the pair (0, 1) gets the counts of 2**

`Single reducer` collects the key-value pairs of the count and check if the pair has a count of 1.

1 representing there are only one directed edge between the two nodes.